# Sequencing the Records ORDER BY issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

First Please understand the problem.  Dont say use

**ORDER By SectionName, ZoneName**

using Order by will shuffle section and zone name order.. but I need to maintain that..

consider below 6 rows 3 columns from one table.

```
Section 1   Z1  1
Section 1   Z2  2
Section 3   Z1  3
Section 3   Z2  4
Section 1   Z1  5
Section 2   Z1  6
```

row number 5 that is for section 1 and zone 1 mean it should come at 2nd position instead on 5th.  remaining should be as it is.  mean I want the result like.

```
Section 1   Z1  1
Section 1   Z1  5
Section 1   Z2  2
Section 3   Z1  3
Section 3   Z2  4
Section 2   Z1  6
```

section and zone name could be anything and third column gonna be almost same mean its gonna be sequence fields.

Please suggest how should I try..

**Update**
Consider we are fetching row one by one from the database into another temp table, where SectionName, ZoneName becoming the unique key, so upto 4th row all seems good, but for the 5 row as Section1 and Zone1 is already in temp Table 
so I want to insert this 5th for near the Section1 and Zone 1 mean near the after the first row .. by this way I will get my required result.

**if we use the order by we will get diff result. please check**

```
 Section 1  Z1  1
 Section 1  Z1  5
 Section 1  Z2  2
 Section 2  Z1  6
 Section 3  Z1  3
 Section 3  Z2  4
```

check section 2 should be at bottom but its in middle..

Comment: Why not `order by sectioncolumn,zonecolumn` ??

Comment: no that can change the order of the section and zone name..  mean if section 2 coming first and if we apply then section1 will be the first one.  I just need to maintain the order of the section and zone.

Comment: I will appreciate first understand the problem,  prove me wrong or prove question a silly one then hit dislike button..

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking for; based on the sample provided, and the expected output, ordering by column 1, column 2 and column 3 should give you exactly what you're asking for.  If that doesn't work, you need a more clear example of data and expected results.

Comment: `using Order by will shuffle section and zone name order`, show us data that is shuffeled incorrectly because of ordering

Comment: I don't actually come out and say this very often, but this is a horrible and unclear question. Your updates and clarifications are making it worse, not better.

Comment: You don't insert records between other records, you just insert the records, and then define the order upon selecting.

Comment: @DeepakSharma, can result output begin with Section 5 for example and be continued with Section 2, 3..?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri i have updated the question.  Mean check what I want and what will I get if use "ORDER BY sectionName,ZoneName"

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables I am not saying to insert in between.  Just consider its table and I want to select in specified order.. I mean if section,zone repeating they should come together..

Comment: You need to explain why "Section 2" should be last.

Comment: @AaronBertrand from the very first table.. you can see Section1 if first section3 is second and Section2 in at third position in first column..so I need to maintain the order of these section.. I have designing a page layout tool which will create the page in same order so we can not change the order else it will change the page layout.. hope it make sense..

Comment: A table is an unordered bag of rows. What *makes* Section 2 last? The third column? BE EXPLICIT.

Comment: @AaronBertrand consider first table is set of rows in table.. and I just use these rows in same orders to create the page layout as I told.. but now problem is that if I added on field on old section (Section1), it will be inserted at last.. and then when I generate the page layout.. it section 1 again for last field we inserted.

Comment: *sigh* I give up, sorry.

Comment: @AaronBertrand no problem. man.. I also gave up by trying lot of things then only I posted question here..

Comment: [Maybe this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/24cd2/1) but I have absolutely no idea if this will work for you since I do not understand any of your descriptions of the actual problem. SQL Server doesn't know what "last field we inserted" nor should you make any assumptions about how data in a table ***appears*** to be ordered. [See #3 here](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/t-sql-tuesday-56-sql-server-assumptions/).

Comment: @AaronBertrand hope it will help.. let me try..

Answer (score 0):

You can't rely on the order of rows in the table.  If you need to maintain a particular order, consider creating a new table to store the order.

Sample Data:

```
create table temp_t (
  section varchar(10),
  zone varchar(2),
  zone_order int
);

insert into temp_t values ('Section 1','Z1',1);
insert into temp_t values ('Section 1','Z2',2);
insert into temp_t values ('Section 3','Z1',3);
insert into temp_t values ('Section 3','Z2',4);
insert into temp_t values ('Section 1','Z1',5);
insert into temp_t values ('Section 2','Z1',6);
```

New table to hold the expected order:

```
create table temp_t_sort (
  section varchar(10),
  zone varchar(2),
  sort_order int
);

insert into temp_t_sort values ('Section 1','Z1',1);
insert into temp_t_sort values ('Section 1','Z2',2);
insert into temp_t_sort values ('Section 3','Z1',3);
insert into temp_t_sort values ('Section 3','Z2',4);
insert into temp_t_sort values ('Section 2','Z1',5);
```

Query to get what you need:

```
select t.section, t.zone, t.zone_order
from temp_t t
join temp_t_sort s on t.section = s.section and t.zone = s.zone
order by s.sort_order, t.zone_order;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you want to preserve ordering of first occurence of combination of (Section, Zone), then append to the end of the combination each repeating combination. This is done by pointing each row on minimal id where the similar combination is found. Then just order by 2 IDs:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( ID INT, S INT, Z INT )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 1, 1, 1 ),
        ( 2, 1, 2 ),
        ( 3, 3, 1 ),
        ( 4, 3, 2 ),
        ( 5, 1, 1 ),
        ( 6, 2, 1 );

WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        ( SELECT    MIN(ID)
                          FROM      @t t2
                          WHERE     t2.S = t1.S AND t2.Z = t1.Z
                        ) AS LinkID
               FROM     @t t1
             )
    SELECT  ID, S, Z
    FROM    cte
    ORDER BY LinkID , ID
```

Output:

```
ID  S   Z
1   1   1
5   1   1
2   1   2
3   3   1
4   3   2
6   2   1
```